# MQTT android Server Connection issue to import the ssl certification using .bks file insertion

Tags: java, android, ssl, mqtt

Mqtt android client code.

This code works well without ssl certificate connection.

```
public void connectToMqttServerTest() {
    String clientId = MqttClient.generateClientId();
    final MqttAndroidClient mqttAndroidClient = new MqttAndroidClient(this.getApplicationContext(), "ssl://10.0.0.50:8883", "AndroidMQTTServer", persistence);
    MqttConnectOptions connectionOptions = new MqttConnectOptions();
    connectionOptions.setCleanSession(true);

    try {
        InputStream srvIn = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.key_store);
        connectionOptions.setSocketFactory(mqttAndroidClient.getSSLSocketFactory(srvIn, "1234"));

    } catch (MqttSecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mqttAndroidClient.setCallback(new MqttCallback() {
        @Override
        public void connectionLost(Throwable cause) {
            System.out.println("mqtt Connection was lost!");
        }

        @Override
        public void messageArrived(String topic, MqttMessage message) throws Exception {
            Log.e("message", message.toString());
            System.out.println("mqtt Message Arrived!: " + topic + ": " + new String(message.getPayload()));
        }

        @Override
        public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken token) {
            System.out.println("mqtt Delivery Complete!");
        }
    });

    try {
        mqttAndroidClient.connect(connectionOptions, null, new IMqttActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(IMqttToken asyncActionToken) {
                System.out.println("mqtt Connection Success!");
                try {
                    mqttAndroidClient.subscribe("res_shdap_11_findDevices", 1);
                    mqttAndroidClient.publish("req_shdap_11_findDevices", new MqttMessage("{\"message\" : \"\"}".getBytes()));
                } catch (MqttException ex) {

                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(IMqttToken asyncActionToken, Throwable exception) {
                System.out.println("mqtt Connection Failure!");
                System.out.println("mqtt throwable: " + exception.toString());
            }
        });
    } catch (MqttException ex) {
        System.out.println("mqtt exception " + ex.toString());
    }
}
```

> Error:
>   MqttException (0) - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Just posting some code saying "this doesn't work" is considered off topic, please read the doc about asking good questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hey Do you know when should arise the SSL Handshake Exception?

Comment: The error implies the broker is using a certificate that has no CA cert in your keystore